# How to add drag-nodes functionality to graph loaded from json file

Tags: sigma.js

I am trying my hands on sigma.js. 
I have the following working example where I am able to load my JSON objects from disk.

```
<script>
sigma.parsers.json( "/data/prc_network.json",
  {container: 'network-graph'},

  function(s) { //This function is passed an instance of Sigma s
    //Initialize nodes as a circle
    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(node, i, a) {
      node.x = Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
      node.y = Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
    });
    s.refresh();
    s.startForceAtlas2();
  });
</script>
```

I was looking at another example [`drag-nodes.html`](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/drag-nodes.html) where it creates some random nodes and then inserts them into the graph and it also defines the `listeners` (for drag/drop events).
Could you please help me around how to add the above code where json is being loaded from file '/data/prc_network.json' to the following ( i want to get rid of creating the random nodes and use the nodes loaded from the physical file). I tried few think but it doesn't work at all.

```
var i,
    s,
    N = 100,
    E = 500,
    g = {
      nodes: [],
      edges: []
    };

// Generate a random graph:
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  g.nodes.push({
    id: 'n' + i,
    label: 'Node ' + i,
    x: Math.random(),
    y: Math.random(),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: '#666'
  });

for (i = 0; i < E; i++)
  g.edges.push({
    id: 'e' + i,
    source: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    target: 'n' + (Math.random() * N | 0),
    size: Math.random(),
    color: '#ccc'
  });

s = new sigma({  graph: g,  container: 'graph-container'});
// Initialize the dragNodes plugin:
var dragListener = sigma.plugins.dragNodes(s, s.renderers[0]);

dragListener.bind('startdrag', function(event) {  console.log(event);});
dragListener.bind('drag', function(event) {  console.log(event);});
dragListener.bind('drop', function(event) { console.log(event);});
dragListener.bind('dragend', function(event) {console.log(event); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution:

```
<script>
var g = {
      nodes: [],
      edges: []
    };

s = new sigma({
  graph: g,
  container: 'container',
   renderer: {
    container: document.getElementById('network-graph'),
    type: 'canvas'
   }
});

sigma.parsers.json( "/data/prc_network.json",s,
  function(s) { //This function is passed an instance of Sigma s
    //Initialize nodes as a circle
    s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(node, i, a) {
      node.x = Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
      node.y = Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length);
    });
    s.refresh();
    s.startForceAtlas2();
  });
</script>
```